# Setting a cookie with max age; max age is lost

Tags: go, cookies

So.. I have this unit test:

```
func TestCookieVoodoo(t *testing.T) {
    req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)

    cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "potato", MaxAge: 1000}

    req.AddCookie(&cookie)

    cookieCopy, _ := req.Cookie("potato")

    println(fmt.Sprintf("Cookie orig: %v", cookie))
    println(fmt.Sprintf("Cookie Copy: %v", *cookieCopy))

    t.Fail()
}
```

When running it, the output is:

```
Cookie orig: {potato    0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC  1000 false false 0  []}
Cookie copy: {potato    0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC  0 false false 0  []}
```

Why does it loose the max age? (same thing happens when setting other cookie fields) Thanks

Comment: A Set-Cookie header must not have a Max-Age attribute. It is that simple. See RFC 6265.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `Request.AddCookie` only add `key` and `value` to the cookie string. the function is:

```golang
func (r *Request) AddCookie(c *Cookie) {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%s=%s", sanitizeCookieName(c.Name), sanitizeCookieValue(c.Value))
    if c := r.Header.Get("Cookie"); c != "" {
        r.Header.Set("Cookie", c+"; "+s)
    } else {
        r.Header.Set("Cookie", s)
    }
}
```

why?

1. this is the definition of `cookie-string`  in `RFC 6265`
2. the `Max-Age` and other fields of cookie is used by client not server. they are config of client. for example: if the the cookie exprires, client doesn't send `key=value` to server. So the fields are ignored in **request**

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [`AddCookie`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=14222:14260#L393) code you can see it attaches a `Cookie` header to the request in the form `<Name>=<Value>`, or appends to an existing `Cookie` header ignoring all other fields of the Cookie struct except for Name and Value.

The Cookie header only has the notion of a `Name` and a `Value`, more information about the `Cookie` header can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie).

A [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header on the other hand would preserve all the fields of the Cookie struct, but this would typically set on an HTTP response. So it wouldn't really make sense to set this on your `http.Request`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Go implementation of [`AddCookie`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=14222:14260#L393) it is only taking the `Name` and `Value` fields.

I believe this is because the `MaxAge` is valid when sending a cookie in a `Response` but irrelevent when making a `Request`. Any cookies the client receives to submit with a request (as in your case) should be validated; valid cookies are then added with `AddCookie` and only their Keys and Values will be submitted with the request.